# why char pointer not giving segmentation fault?

Tags: c, pointers

Today's morning i just got surprised with the behavior of C.(It really surprised me.)

If i write a code like this :

```
char *txt;
strncpy(txt,"hello",4);
printf("%s\n",txt);
```

Then i know that it will give segmentation fault because i have not allocated memory to 'txt' pointer. ok ....Now see this code :

```
char *txt = (char *) calloc(0,sizeof(char ));
strncpy(txt,"hello",4);
printf("%s\n",txt);
```

Still i have allocated 0 bytes to 'txt' , but i just got surprised why it is not giving segmentation fault ?, instead of giving segmentation fault , it is giving right answer "hell".

**Can anyone one explain me such type of behavior of C ?**

Comment: Try calling `free(txt)` and see what happens...

Comment: Every thing is going fine when m calling free(txt), i mean no error is coming and it is giving correct answer. @pat

Answer (score 1):

A segfault is **never** guaranteed by the C standard. Generally there is just "undefined behavior": if you do X, anything at all is allowed to happen. Sometimes, on some operating systems, you will get a segfault. But maybe you get "lucky" and nothing bad happens. Or you corrupt some memory that you'll use a little later, causing your program to crash for no apparent reason.

In this case the undefined behavior is caused by you writing into memory that you have not allocated. Maybe it works, maybe it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the operating system has actually allocated more than the requested number of bytes and you're writing to that, or that the operating system returned *some* pointer which doesn't cause a segfault.

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/calloc

> If size is zero, the behavior is implementation defined (null pointer may be returned, or some non-null pointer may be returned that may not be used to access storage)

Obviously you should **not** rely on this.